# Does not work gitlab-runner queue for docker executor

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have:

CentOS 6 final OS; 
GitLab 11.10.4; 
Gitlab-runner 11.10.1 with android executor

My part of `config.toml`:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "android-1"
```

How you can see `concurrent = 1` 
Let's look on my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: runmymind/docker-android-sdk:latest

variables:
  GRADLE_USER_HOME: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.gradle

cache:
  key: $CI_PROJECT_NAME
  paths:
    - .gradle/wrapper/
    - .gradle/caches/

before_script:
  - echo $JAVA_HOME
  - echo $ANDROID_HOME
  - echo $PATH
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

stages:
  - check

checkStage:
  stage: check
  script:
    - set +e
    - du -sh $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.gradle/wrapper
    - du -sh $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.gradle/caches
    - set -e
    - ./gradlew check
  artifacts:
    when: on_failure
    paths:
    - build_results
```

It works. But when i am pushing in several branches, i have:
On one job:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.10.1 (1f513601)
  on android-1 cf4dbddf
Using Docker executor with image runmymind/docker-android-sdk:latest ...
Using locally found image version due to if-not-present pull policy
Using docker image sha256:05edf996f2cf3a0be9c332ca88e4ffd1698b7d59b1c5318b48491033e062e639 for runmymind/docker-android-sdk:latest ...
Running on runner-cf4dbddf-project-918-concurrent-0 via git-ci-runner...
WARNING: Possibly zombie container runner-cf4dbddf-project-918-concurrent-0-predefined-1 is disconnected from network bridge
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/android/MYPROJECT/.git/
Fetching changes...
Checking out 21ff9883 as branch_for_test_it_1...
Removing .gradle/
....
OK
```

On my other job:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.10.1 (1f513601)
  on android-runner-1 cf4dbddf
Using Docker executor with image runmymind/docker-android-sdk:latest ...
Using locally found image version due to if-not-present pull policy
Using docker image sha256:05edf996f2cf3a0be9c332ca88e4ffd1698b7d59b1c5318b48491033e062e639 for runmymind/docker-android-sdk:latest ...
Running on runner-cf4dbddf-project-918-concurrent-0 via git-ci-runner...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/android/MYPROJECT/.git/
Fetching changes...
Checking out 21ff9883 as branch_for_test_it_2...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error: No such container: 9721b3efbc71ababc12da8606307bd36c56b08e6500605a3ddbc9e42855498d6 (executor_docker.go:976:0s)
```

I am understanding, that it works with one container per project (not for branch).
And how i understand, we have two ways to resolve this issue:

1) find out how to create new container for each branch;
2) find out how to make gitlab-runner queue for docker executor

I want to ask you, how can we realize one of the ways ? As for me, better to use second way, because in the first way, we will use a lot of resources of computer. But it is ok. Tell me please, how we can resolve these variants, that i wrote above ?